# QT. JSON. QJsonDocument. Конвертация double в scientific по умолчанию. Как избежать

Tags: c++, json, qt, парсер, qt5

Занимаюсь получением текущей погоды с API OpenWeather (`https://api.openweathermap.org/`).

Делаю реквест, получаю строку и пытаюсь её распарсить как JSON используя QJsonDocument.

Однако в процессе этого возникает ощутимая проблема конвертации - время рассвета, например `1648695812`, переходит автоматом в scientific double `1.6487e+09`, что очевидно сжирает часть необходимых секунд.

Конвертация происходит на этапе формирования QJsonDocument, проверено с помощью QVariantMap и дебага. На этапе получения данных с сервера проблем нет.

```
if(reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {

        QString ReplyText = reply->readAll();
        QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(ReplyText.toUtf8());
        weather_obj = doc.object().value("current").toObject();

        reply->deleteLater();
    }
```

Писать свой парсер под такой таск желания нет, да и как-то глупо выглядит, поэтому хотелось бы узнать, есть какой-нибудь обходной путь конвертации в Json.

*Подойдут любые костыли.*

Comment: Автоматически конвертация не происходит, все конвертируется так, как вы сами указали. А посему приведите фрагмент кода, где вы разбираете проблемный параметр.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Класс `QJsonValue` имеет метод [toInt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonvalue.html#toInt), который переведет значение в тип int. А его можно напрямую присвоить типу `time_t`.

Если на вашей платформе тип `time_t` беззнаковый, то лучше выполнять промежуточное преобразование в `QString`, а из него уже в `unsigned int`.

Comment: Все на удивление работает, но тогда у меня встает вопрос, почему в рамках QVariantMap это дело показывается уже в виде double `scientific`, и каким магическим образом происходит обратная конвертация в сохранением потерянных по факту значений (если оно все же хранится в преобразованном виде)

Comment: Что происходит внутри QVariantMap - не раскрывается, и почему данное число этот класс рассматривает как double - непонятно. В моем примере не происходит преобразование QJsonValue в QVariant. Исходный json - это строка, а из строки можно сразу получить int без потери точности.